# conflict multiple .load() events of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have load the data with the `$('#result').load('test.php')` file, that is completely working properly.

here is the `test.php` screenshoot
[image]

now here is my loaded file in lightbox:
[image]

In my `test.php` file I also load another file in a lightbox with on click event. The lightbox appear correctly with the new loaded file. here is the code to call the lighbox:

```
jQuery('#wt_opp_coll .coun').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).jpLightBox({
            width: 500,
            height: 250,
            url: 'components/content/test_file.php'
            //message: 'Just Testing the file'
        });
    });
```

with this my new loaded file that is `test_file.php` appearing well in the lightbox but my last loaded file `test.php` disappearing on lightbox, as you see on the second screenshoot only lightbox appear not the details in the background like first screenshoot.

Please help me to stop disappearing my last loaded file(`test.php`) also.

**NOTE:** I have also use `.load()` function in lighbox to load the url.

Comment: Does the background data disappears or is replaced by the new test_file.php data?

Comment: @SharkyLV thanks for your reply, the background data is disappears not replaced, i have the clue but don't know how to solve, that is because the both files are showing with the `.load()` but when i call the second file in lighbox `test_file.php` then the first one disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done anything with LightBox, but could the issue be that you are replacing `#wt_opp_coll .coun` with the new lightbox?

```
jQuery('#wt_opp_coll .coun').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).jpLightBox({
            width: 500,
            height: 250,
            url: 'components/content/test_file.php'
            //message: 'Just Testing the file'
        });
    });
```

Second line has `jQuery(this)` which indicates to the parent `#wt_opp_coll .coun`. So what I think is happening is that the lightbox is replacing `#wt_opp_coll .coun` content.

Comment: I think the easiest way to check is replace `jQuery(this)` with any other block in your code. eg. `jQuery("body")` and see if that block disappears.

Comment: noop the second file is added in other div that is in outside of `jQuery(this)` means child of body and parent of `jQuery(this)`

Answer (score 0):

I cant tell you what causes this strange issue but I also had a problem with it a while back.  The way that I solved it was by using livequery to handle my click events.  Don't ask me why, I've gone through the libraries and documentation for hours, as well as tried to find an answer from others to no avail.

Give it a shot, if you don't have a problem using livequery, it may be your solution.

Here's a snippet of my code, it is used for up to 50 different instances of the load call, all of which work.  Some were links dynamically created by other loaded data as well.

```
function ajaxContent(link, sel, reg, extReg) {
$(sel).not(link).removeClass("active");
$(link).addClass("active");

var toLoad = $(link).attr('href')+ ' ' + extReg;

$(reg).fadeOut('slow',loadContent);

function loadContent() {
    $(reg).load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
}

function showNewContent() {
    $(reg).delay(200).fadeIn('slow');
}

}

$(document).ready(function() {

// Top left "main" nav
$('#jax-nav li a').livequery("click", function(event) {
    ajaxContent(event.target, '#jax-nav li a', '#page-content', '#ajax-out');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try placing an empty div on your html for lightbox

```
<div id="lightBoxDiv"></div>
```

and edit your code

```
jQuery('#wt_opp_coll .coun').click(function(){
        jQuery("#lightBoxDiv").jpLightBox({
            width: 500,
            height: 250,
            url: 'components/content/test_file.php'
            //message: 'Just Testing the file'
        });
    });
```

you will also need to flush this div's content on close button other wise it will effect your base html

place this code in you close button

```
$("#lightBoxDiv").html('');
```